# Two identical NFS shares, but only one of the two gives Stale file handle errors

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a Linux (raspbian) server:

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux hester 4.19.97-v7l+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

With two directories that have the same user/group/permissions:

```sh
$ ls -ld /mnt/storage/gitea/ /mnt/storage/hester/
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 26 Mar  2 10:20 /mnt/storage/gitea/
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 21 Feb 21 11:26 /mnt/storage/hester/
```

These two directories are exported with the same parameters in the exports file:

```sh
$ cat /etc/exports
/mnt/storage/hester     192.168.1.15(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/mnt/storage/gitea      192.168.1.15(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

On another machine (the 192.168.1.15 mentioned in the exports file) I mount both, successfully :

```sh
$ mount /mnt/storage/gitea/
$ echo $?
0
$ mount /mnt/storage/hester/
$ echo $?
0
```

But now weird things happen:

```sh
$ ls -l /mnt/storage/
ls: cannot access '/mnt/storage/gitea': Stale file handle
total 0
d????????? ? ?      ?        ?            ? gitea
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 21 Feb 21 11:26 hester
```

I really can't figure

- what's the source of the error, and above all
- where I could look for a difference between the two.

I'm open to suggestions for further investigations or answers for the my doubts. Thanks in advance for any useful input!

Comment: did you refresh exports `exportfs -ra`?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, I did. I also restarted both servers.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, which was to explicitly add an `fsid` option in exports:

```sh
$ cat /etc/exports
/mnt/storage/hester     192.168.1.15(rw,sync,fsid=20,no_subtree_check)
/mnt/storage/gitea      192.168.1.15(rw,sync,fsid=21,no_subtree_check)
```

I'm not entirely sure as to the reason why this works. From the man page I get that "NFS needs to be able to identify each filesystem that it exports. Normally it will use a UUID for the filesystem (if the filesystem has such a thing) or the device number of the device holding the filesystem (if the filesystem is stored on the device)."

Both these mountpoints are on the same filesystem, so according to the man page they should have the same fsid, but this causes the same directory to be exported, so I think it means that each *export* needs to have a separate fsid.

One more note: /mnt/storage is an XFS filesystem over a RAID3, so this could also have made NFS confused about UUIDs of devices.